# How to remove duplicate records from PySpark DataFrame based on a condition?

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Assume that I have a PySpark DataFrame like below:

```
# Prepare Data
data = [('Italy', 'ITA'), \
    ('China', 'CHN'), \
    ('China', None), \
    ('France', 'FRA'), \
    ('Spain', None), \
    ('Taiwan', 'TWN'), \
    ('Taiwan', None)
  ]

# Create DataFrame
columns = ['Name', 'Code']
df = spark.createDataFrame(data = data, schema = columns)
df.show(truncate=False)
```

[image]

As you can see, a few countries are repeated twice (China & Taiwan in the above example). I want to delete records that satisfy the following conditions:

1. The column 'Name' is repeated more than once

AND

2. The column 'Code' is Null.

Note that column 'Code' can be Null for countries which are not repeated, like Spain. I want to keep those records.

The expected output will be like:

| Name | Code |
| --- | --- |
| 'Italy' | 'ITA' |
| 'China' | 'CHN' |
| 'France' | 'FRA' |
| 'Spain' | Null |
| 'Taiwan' | 'TWN' |

In fact, I want to have one record for every country. Any idea how to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to obtain non-null rows first, use the `row_number` window function to group by `Name` column and sort the `Code` column. Since null is considered the smallest in Spark order by, `desc` mode is used. Then take the first row of each group.

```
df = df.withColumn('rn', F.expr('row_number() over (partition by Name order by Code desc)')).filter('rn = 1').drop('rn')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use window.PartitionBy to achieve your desired results:

```
from pyspark.sql import Window
import pyspark.sql.functions as f


df1 = df.select('Name', f.max('Code').over(Window.partitionBy('Name')).alias('Code')).distinct()
df1.show()
```

Output:

```
+------+----+
|  Name|Code|
+------+----+
| China| CHN|
| Spain|null|
|France| FRA|
|Taiwan| TWN|
| Italy| ITA|
+------+----+
```

Comment: Thanks. Is there a guarantee that max value of column 'Code' is not the Null value? Does the Spark consider Null as the lowest value?

Comment: yes thats correct

Answer (score 0):

Here is one approach :

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import col
df = df.dropDuplicates(subset=["Name"],keep='first')
```

Comment: Thanks. But, dropDuplicates() in PySpark doesn't have the argument 'keep'. Also, there is no guarantee that always the first record is not Null.

Answer (score 0):

There will almost certainly be a cleverer way to do this, but for the sake of a lesson, what if you:

1. made a new dataframe with just 'Name'
2. dropped duplicates on that
3. deleted records where Code = 'null' from initial table
4. do a left join between new table and old table for 'Code'

I've added Australia with no country code just so you can see it works for that case as well

```
import pandas as pd

data = [('Italy', 'ITA'), \
    ('China', 'CHN'), \
    ('China', None), \
    ('France', 'FRA'), \
    ('Spain', None), \
    ('Taiwan', 'TWN'), \
    ('Taiwan', None), \
    ('Australia', None)
  ]

# Create DataFrame
columns = ['Name', 'Code']
df = pd.DataFrame(data = data, columns = columns)
print(df)

# get unique country names
uq_countries = df['Name'].drop_duplicates().to_frame()
print(uq_countries)

# remove None
non_na_codes = df.dropna()
print(non_na_codes)

# combine
final = pd.merge(left=uq_countries, right=non_na_codes, on='Name', how='left')
print(final)
```

Comment: Thanks. Does it work for PySpark DataFrame?

Comment: @jaketclarke, I would suggest dropping the null values first and then the duplicates because if we have a country with a `null` code first and you do drop duplicates it would remove the others with valid codes and then the `dropna` would drop this entry too

Comment: @Mohammad apologies for misreading the framework. The syntax is probably slightly different but the approach will definitely work. Borrow this from the other answer df.dropDuplicates(subset=["Name"],keep='first'), drop the second column, drop the nulls, and look up from whats left